# Scheduled auto reply - Email

Tags: email, plesk, webmail, roundcube

I have been trying for a while but cannot see any way to have out of office Auto replies run on a schedule.

I currently use Thunderbird as my email client, [Roundcube](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) as my webmail client app, and [Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/) to control the [cloud e-mail server](https://www.ionos.com/office-solutions/email-hosting) from 1&1 [Ionus](https://www.ionos.com/).

I am trying to set up an email auto response between 6pm and 8am the next day to tell customers who email that the emails are not monitored and that to get in touch they should call.

Currently all I can see is the option to create an out of office and turn on/off manually. While that works, there are a number of email addresses and to do this for all, every day could get tedious

Is there a way for me to set up the out of office on a schedule?

Comment: As noted in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1073671 to do it with Thunderbird, you have to leave your computer on, logged on and Thunderbird running. Who hosts your email? There may be a solution there.

Comment: I had seen that, which Is why I thought Id best ask the question as it is not feasible to always have the computer left running. Ideally I was hoping there was a way to do this via Plesk or Roundcube. I use a dedicated server with Ionos, they dont take anything to do with these matters, they only help if theres a technical issue

Comment: 1&1 does not have it in the email product you rent from them? How many email addresses do you need to add auto-replies to? I have a cunning plan.... but I need details. Also, weekends? https://images.app.goo.gl/kz2uunXCyz1DyjB4A

Comment: @K7AAY as mentioned in the question, there is an auto respond option but it would require me to turn on every afternoon at 6pm and then turn off every morning at 8am. Ideally I am looking to find out if there is a way to set it up on a schedule so that it turns on automatically at set times

Comment: How ... many ... email ... addresses ... do ... you ... need ... to ... add ... auto-replies ... to?  Do ... you ... want ... auto-replies ... from 1800 .... Friday ... to .... 0800 ...  Monday?